# jQuery removing characters after apostrophe when sending string from HTML to jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to pass a variable, a first name with an apostrophe, from HTML to jQuery. By the time the value gets to jQuery, the string is missing all the characters after the apostrophe.

Name Example: Test'Ing

This is part of the form. I fill the list dynamically and the name appears correct when pulled from the database:

```
<?php echo "<select id='hiringManager' class='dropdown_form' name='hiringManager'>";
    echo "<option disabled selected>Hiring Manager</option>";
        while ($result_row = mysqli_fetch_row($hiring_manager_query)) {
             echo "<option value='" . $result_row[0] . "'>" . $result_row[0] . "</option>";
        }
echo "</select>" ?>
```

And then I get the value from the form and display it in a jQuery modal for confirmation:

```
$('#hiringManagerModal').text($('#hiringManager').val());
```

The resulting text shown is:

"Test" instead of "Test'Ing"

I have poked around but have not been able to find a post that addresses this, or I could not be phrasing the issue correctly in the search.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the PHP code. I have replaced the `'`s with `"`s and `"`s with `'`s. The outputted HTML earlier was,

```
<select id='hiringManager' class='dropdown_form' name='hiringManager'>
<option disabled selected>Hiring Manager</option>
<option value='test'ing'>test'ing</option> <!-- In this option, the value is test instead of test'ing -->
</select>
```

and now after all the replacements, it is,

```
<select id="hiringManager" class="dropdown_form" name="hiringManager">
<option disabled selected>Hiring Manager</option>
<option value="test'ing">test'ing</option><!-- Now, here the value is test'ing, as required -->
</select>
```

What really happens is that when `'` is encountered, the string gets terminated and as a result only "test" gets outputted instead of "test'ing".

The corrected PHP code after all the replacements:

```
<?php
echo '<select id="hiringManager" class="dropdown_form" onchange="displayInModal();" name="hiringManager">';
echo '<option disabled selected>Hiring Manager</option>';
while ($result_row = mysqli_fetch_row($hiring_manager_query)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $result_row[0] . '">' . $result_row[0] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>'
?>
```

with,

```
$('#hiringManagerModal').text($('#hiringManager').val());
```

Now, the same problem would arise with

```
<option value="test"ing"></option>
```

Other way:

```
echo '<option value='test\'ing'></option>';
```

Comment: Yeah that is one of the things I tried and I get the same result :-(

Comment: @user3282173 try going with the alternate solution.

Comment: Ok, with that change I get Test\ instead of Test. For some reason it does not like the \ in `str_replace("'","\'",$result_row[0])` if I just do `str_replace("'","'",$result_row[0])` my result is TestIng. So I feel like this is progress but not quite there.

Comment: Solved. The problem was with the PHP code. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much for your help and quick responses.